# Copy htm and its supported files and directory to other directory using CMD

Tags: cmd, directory, copy, xcopy

I have few html files with .htm extension and its supported files in another directory.

For example : html file name is 41debcd7-75f2-469a-8833-8bda79995009.htm and its supported  directory name is 41debcd7-75f2-469a-8833-8bda79995009_files, which contains styles/images/etc used in html file.

this html file is created using MS word Save as Type-> "Web Page(*.htm;*.html)"

I want to copy HTML file with its supported files to some other directory using CMD. I am able to copy HTML files(have multiple html in directory) and supported directory with below command but all support files are not getting copied(only html copied)
xcopy " *.htm" "f:\TestCMD"  /s /e

Can anyone please help in copying html and all supported files of html using cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XCOPY` command is good for copying subdirectory structures.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "FILENAME=41debcd7-75f2-469a-8833-8bda79995009.html"
SET "TARGET_DIR=C:\src\t\htest"

FOR %%f IN ("%FILENAME%") DO (
    SET "SUBDIR=%%~nf_files"
    IF NOT EXIST "%TARGET_DIR%\!SUBDIR!" (MKDIR "%TARGET_DIR%\!SUBDIR!")

    COPY "%FILENAME%" "%TARGET_DIR%"
    XCOPY /V /S /E /I "!SUBDIR!" "%TARGET_DIR%\!SUBDIR!"
)
```

Comment: i tried this, it is creating only folder with name "41debcd7-75f2-469a-8833-8bda79995009" and it is empty. Output should be directory name  "41debcd7-75f2-469a-8833-8bda79995009_files" with its subfolder/files and html file in root with this directory. Also i have multiple html files that i want to copy

Comment: Is the 41debcd7-75f2-469a-8833-8bda79995009.html file in the current directory when you run this?

Comment: Yes. my mistake in typo. It is copying html file i.e. "41debcd7-75f2-469a-8833-8bda79995009.htm" and creating empty directory "41debcd7-75f2-469a-8833-8bda79995009"

Comment: As per output directory name should be "41debcd7-75f2-469a-8833-8bda79995009_files" and it should contains files and images used in html file

Comment: I added "_files" to the subdirectory name. Is it still empty?

Comment: Yes. It is seems to be working now. Here is the script 


SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "FILENAME=41debcd7-75f2-469a-8833-8bda79995009.htm"
SET "TARGET_DIR=F:\TestCMD"

FOR %%f IN ("%FILENAME%") DO (
    SET "SUBDIR=%%~nf_files"
    IF NOT EXIST "%TARGET_DIR%\!SUBDIR!" (MKDIR "%TARGET_DIR%\!SUBDIR!")

    COPY "%FILENAME%" "%TARGET_DIR%"
    XCOPY /V /S /E /I "!SUBDIR!" "%TARGET_DIR%\!SUBDIR!"
)


if possible can you please help for iterating loop for all .htm files present in directory?
I am also trying same at my end.

Comment: Please edit the question to put code. Code in comments does not work well. Do you have it working on *.htm now?

Comment: Hi lit, below code is working now. Thanks for your help

Comment: SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


SET "FILENAME=*.htm"
SET "TARGET_DIR=C:\src\t\htest"

FOR %%f IN ("%FILENAME%") DO (

    
  SET "SUBDIR=%%~nf_files"
      IF NOT EXIST "%TARGET_DIR%\!SUBDIR!" (MKDIR "%TARGET_DIR%\!SUBDIR!"   
   COPY "%%~nf.htm" "%TARGET_DIR%"
 XCOPY /V /S /E /I "!SUBDIR!" "%TARGET_DIR%\!SUBDIR!"
 )
)